# Azure Event Hubs: How to grant SAS tokens to Javascript publishers (running in browser)?

Tags: javascript, security, azure, authentication, azure-eventhub

I am building a website analytics solution based on Azure Event Hubs. I have Javascript code embedded in each web page that publishes events directly to an Event Hub via the [Azure Event Hubs REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790674.aspx).

The REST API requires that each call be authenticated via a SAS token. My questions is - Do I have to code up a server side endpoint that will provide my publishers with temporary tokens before they can start publishing?

Are there alternative approaches?

1. Does the REST API provide this "authenticate" end point out of the box? (couldn't find it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790674.aspx))
2. Or, how **terrible, security wise** would it be to have a token hard coded into the client-side code?
3. Or, **technically feasible but security-wise much worse than option 2**, Hard-code the Event Hub's Shared Access Key in the client-side code and use something like the (unofficial) [Azure ServiceBus JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/ddobric/ServiceBusJavaScriptSdk/wiki/What-is-Azure-Service-Bus-JavaScript-SDK%3F) to [generate](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2015/01/26/eventhubs-support-for-azure-servicebus-javascript-sdk.aspx) the SAS token on the fly?

Comment: Consider #4: A Web API gateway to which browsers authenticate and post data as usual, that batches and posts events to Event Hub using the .NET SDK. That's actually the architecture presented in Pluralsight's Event Hub course

Comment: Tx! I thought about that but it has a drawback in that it would require me to pay for more CPU, hosting the Web API gateway at my expense.

Comment: Are you sure? First, you are using Event Hub for a scenario it wasn't designed to address. Second, using the SDK and batching is a *lot* more efficient than HTTP. You could end up with a *cheaper* solution if eg. you could batch 20-50 events and used fewer throughput units. Third, if you have a browser, you already have a web application somewhere, to which the browser has already authenticated. You may not need a separate gateway, just add another controller

Comment: The scenario is supported by EH - Think of the browsers as a devices (IoT). Also, batching (on my CPU) is still more expensive than single events coming in from browsers (not my CPUs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Hub REST api does not provide an authentication end point. You will have to code up the generation of SAS tokens per client (browser or device) on your server side (may be as part of your AuthN/Z routines?). Refer to [RedDog.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RedDog.ServiceBus/) nuget package to generate SAS tokens for your Event Hub, per client. Also this [article](http://fabriccontroller.net/iot-with-azure-service-bus-event-hubs-authenticating-and-sending-from-any-type-of-device-net-and-js-samples/) on IoT, explains authenticating against Event Hubs using the aforementioned package.

In my opinion, I would much rather do the above and rule out #2 and #3. They (2 & 3) leave the solution vulnerable and violate best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the example set by Google Analytics and other browser analytics providers, the second alternative in my question is quite acceptable.

That is, a SAS token can be generated on a "per site" (or "per analytics customer") basis and be shared by all browsers that this site is tracked on. The generation of the keys can be done via a tool like Sandrino Di Mattia's [Event Hubs Signature Generator](https://github.com/sandrinodimattia/RedDog/releases) based on his [RedDog](https://github.com/sandrinodimattia/RedDog) Azure library.

This way tokens can be generated once when a publisher is onboarded and there is no need for an online Web API endpoint to be constantly available.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you could consider Application Insights for event ingestion. Depending on the type of event collection you're doing, you could be using it and exporting data using built in archiving mechanisms or querying endpoints for specific events from time to time. App Insights was designed for JS in-browser scenarios, can handle a large number of RPS + you get some reports, analytics, querying endpoints and some other interesting features. It provides an SDK and JS lib you can use, and implemnts batching for you using browser's local storage.

As a side note, consider that browsers (and any other JS code running on it) as an insecure client. That means, even if you write a mechanism to do a request to a server-side app written by you to get the SAS key, any developer will be able to intercept in memory. So, the most secure thing you could do is a) have a server-side code that generates a short-lived SAS key and b) let your clients authenticate before calling this server-side code. Or, ignore the problem and filter invalid events you receive.

Both GA and App Insights work by exposing a common key. As far as I know, Google Analytics uses heuristics to filter invalid requests. I suppose App Insights do the same.